# DataGridView Doesn't Reflect Changes Made on DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, dataview

I'm struggling with getting my `DataGridView` to bind to my `DataTable`, so I decided to try a super simple example.

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

        dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "John", 25);
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Jane", 30);
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Bob", 40);

        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

However, even after this code gets executed, `dataGridView.Rows.Count` is still `0`, and I'm struggling to understand why. I've tried multiple other things as well (used `BindingSource` with `RefreshBindings`, tried turning off `AutoGenerateColumns`, etc).

How can I populate my DataGridView using the DataTable? Am I missing somthing obvious?

Comment: That's a new grid: `DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();`  Not the one on your form.  Reference that one.

Comment: The DGV is not automatically repainted.  To get update the trick is to set the datasource to null after updating the datatable " dataGridView.DataSource = null;dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

Answer (score 0):

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "John", 25);
dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Jane", 30);
dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Bob", 40);
dataTable.SaveChanges();

// Make sure to create the DataGridView after the DataTable is populated
DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true; // Enable AutoGenerateColumns to create columns automatically
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).